# Bootstrap full width footer without fixing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement of creating a full width footer. But it should not be fixed to the screen. It should be visible only when you scroll to the bottom of the page.

Using `navbar-fixed-bottom` would make the footer fully wide, but it also fixes it to the screen.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer_nav">
            <div class="container-fluid footer_c">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a  style="color:#4b4b4b;  font-size:0.9em;" href="/ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div></nav>
```

Can anybody let me how to do it.

Comment: Where is you HTML code?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think bootstrap gives you non fixed footer. You can use simple Row class or override footer class in css

**HTML**

```
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid footer_c">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a style="color:#4b4b4b;  font-size:0.9em;" href="/ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer{
  width:100%;
  height:20%; //your desired height
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:green;
}
```

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgqWaV

Answer (score 0):

In general the bootstrap footer will have `position: fixed` style in the class. That's the reason for sticking footer at the bottom of the screen. What you need to do is overriding the position of footer by adding a style  `position: relative;` to the footer. This will make footer at the bottom end where the page finishes.

Just add this style in your css

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-fixed-top {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It made the footer disappear, in a smaller screen

Comment: Please check whether you have given any media query to footer. In general the above mentioned lines will not hide the footer in smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `.container` class which has a fixed width (the value depends on the size of the screen/window), the class `.container-fluid` will give the full width property.

```
<footer class="container-fluid">
</footer>
```